# How can I identify my network hardware bandwidth capacity in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter, performance-monitor

I am running a program in two terminals. One is makes 50 concurrent TLS connections and the second at 10 concurrent connections. It is important for me to monitor the network resources to decide on the right number of concurrent workers I can run. I run `nethogs` and can see the current utilizations. My quesiton how can I know what is my device's capacity? As per the manufacturer, the network card capacity is 867 Mbps. But I do not see his reflected in the output. Can you please help me identify my network capacity.
[image]

Comment: This seems to be WLAN, so have a look at `iw wlp2s0 station dump`. Actual speed can vary due to interference by other WLAN stations, microwave ovens, Bluetooth, etc.

Comment: I would use [iperf3](https://iperf.fr/) for such tasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link speed in general depends on the capacity of *both* ends. For example, it won't matter if your client device supports 867 Mbps if the access point happens to be much slower than that.

Additionally, for Wi-Fi, the link speed may change over time and depends greatly on the environment conditions (signal strength, interference, etc.) and on the common supported features by both ends. Usually the *advertised* maximum speed is "under perfect conditions" (and with all features supported).

- The advertised capacity might be through 2–3 MIMO streams, but the other device only supports one.
- The advertised capacity might be for 802.11ac, but the other device only supports 802.11n (or environment conditions don't allow anything better).
- The advertised capacity might be for wide channels (40 MHz, 80 MHz, even 160 MHz) but the other device only supports 'standard' 20 MHz channels or the environment doesn't allow anything better.
- The advertised capacity might be under the assumption that there's only one client and only one access point (basically no interference or collisions at all), while in reality that's almost never true.

To examine the *current* link information on Linux, use `iw`:

- `iw wlp2s0 link`
- `iw wlp2s0 station dump`

To get a general list of Wi-Fi features supported by your device, use `iw phy`. Unfortunately there is no tool for comparing those against a nearby Wi-Fi network (at least none that I know of).